# Emacs interactive read escape sequence

Tags: emacs, insert

I'm writing simple elisp function, that takes 3 arguments interactively: from, to and separator. Then it inserts a sequence of numbers:

```
(defun gen-seq (from to sep)
  "Generates sequence of numbers FROM .. TO with separator SEP"
  (interactive "nFrom: \nnTo: \nMSeparator: ")
  (insert (mapconcat 'number-to-string (number-sequence from to) sep)))
```

But when the `sep` is `\n`, it generates something like

```
1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10
```

Is it possible to achieve a column of numbers with this function in my Emacs buffer?

Comment: Tangentially, you might find the [tiny](https://github.com/abo-abo/tiny) library of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enter a newline as separator by typing `C-q C-j`. See [Inserting Text](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Inserting-Text.html#Inserting-Text) in the emacs manual for details.

Answer (score 1):

Nick's answer is the standard approach for entering newlines, but if you really want Emacs to **read** the string argument as if it were an elisp quoted string, you can do that:

```el
(defun gen-seq (from to sep)
  "Generates sequence of numbers FROM .. TO with separator SEP"
  (interactive "nFrom: \nnTo: \nMSeparator: ")
  (let* ((sepesc (replace-regexp-in-string "\"" "\\\\\"" sep))
         (sepnew (car (read-from-string (concat "\"" sepesc "\"")))))
    (insert (mapconcat 'number-to-string (number-sequence from to) sepnew))))
```

You can also use `(interactive "x")` to **read** an argument, except the user would need to type the double quotes: `"\n"`